# How to fix the code stopping execution after one?

Tags: javascript, html

This code is used to print random numbers from an array whenever the button is clicked and the result will be shown in a popup and the console.

It is a lottery system that chooses a random number from the array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lottey Winner </h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-target="#test" id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">
          Winner
        </button>
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">THE WINNER ISSSS</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="test"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const a = ["12", "34", "45", "67"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    window.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(a[random]);
    });

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a[random];
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know how to fix it, it just stops the execution after one.

Comment: @Ivar probably not; while the question could be clearer, OP seems want the opposite (run multiple times). The code is already running multiple times, but displaying the same number each time, which led the OP to conclude the handler breaks after running once.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing much to do here, just move this statement

`const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);`

inside the `myFunction`.

This will generate a new random number when you click on the button.

```
function myFunction() {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a[random];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `element.removeEventListener` at the end of your EventListerner function in order to remove this event for your button.

```
const a = ["12", "34", "45", "67"];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(a[random]);
});

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a[random];
  window.removeEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(a[random]);
  });
}
```

Be careful, in your code you add the click event for all your window and not only for your button

In place you could do this :

```
const a = ["12", "34", "45", "67"];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(a[random]);
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a[random];
}, {
  once: true
});

// Don't forget to remove your onclick property for your button
```

Comment: Where should I add that

Comment: I've edit my post for give a better explanation, but I recommend you to use the second solution, I sometimes encountered bugs with the first solution.